# Configure docker-compose in order to have communication between celery app and redis broker

Tags: python, docker, flask, redis, celery

I have a python app which contains an instance of Celery:

**tasks.py:**

```
from celery import Celery
from APIGateway.urls import REACTION_URL

BACKEND = BROKER = 'redis://172.18.0.7:6379'
celery = Celery(__name__, backend=BACKEND, broker=BROKER)


@celery.task
def my_task(*params):
    ...
```

I create a task in this way:

```
params = ...
task = my_task.delay(params)
result = task.get()
```

The previous celery instance wants to communicate with the redis broker/backend which is hosted into a separate docker container.

**docker-compose.yaml:**

```
version: '2'
services:
  gateway:
    image: dicetellers/apigateway
    ports:
      - "5000:5000"
    networks:
      dice_network:
        ipv4_address: 172.18.0.2

  redis-gateway:
    image: redis
    ports:
      - "6379:6379"
    networks:
      dice_network:
        ipv4_address: 172.18.0.7

networks:
  dice_network:
    driver: bridge
    ipam:
      config:
        - subnet: 172.18.0.0/16
```

I tried also to change the default configuration of redis, by updating the `redis.conf` file, but it didn't work.
Someone knows if I'm doing something wrong?

Comment: There isn't a clear issue in the question? Are you getting an error? What's the problem with your setup?

Comment: It could be good for you to move to a recent version of docker engine 2 (2016) -> 3.7 (latest).

Comment: @rdas you're right. By reading again my question, I explained bad my problem. I don't have an error, but when i create a new task, celery can't put it into the redis queue, because (i think) it can't reach the queue. Am i managing wrong the addresses or the celery config?

Comment: @Victor i tried, but something in my docker-compose file is not compatible with docker-compose 3

Comment: Please post the logs from celery

Comment: Celery doesn't produce any log, because it doesn't "create" any task